# UK Visit Visa Guidance - Amount to show in Bank Statement

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I have been reading many questions and thought to ask a particular question regarding my plans.

I have been invited by a company in UK to attend a course, they will be covering the Hotel Expense + Air Tickets. And will be providing the invitation letter.
However i will be paying the tickets for my wife and kids.

I am using 4 different banks, and i am a sole proprietor. Usually my income comes in my personal account. 
I have bank accounts since many years. So there is a good amount of Credit / Debit - Transactions..  Be it small or big amounts.. 
I am a Tax Filer since 2012 in my home country too.

My main concern is if currently my account statement is showing a little low ending amount balance (My Father will give me some funds though if need be)

- Should i wait a month or two and than apply for Visa? So in due course i can have a increase in my income ? Will this be counted as "Funds Parking" ?
- Normally how many days/weeks we have to wait for no big credit to occur in bank, and print the statement to apply for visa?
- What amount should be shown in Ending balance, if the visit if for 10 days (2 adults and 2 kids (youngsters)).
- Since i have some amount but a bit low, can i use my Father as a sponsor too, or you think the ideal case is to wait and make my Statement (ending balance) a little strong and than apply?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. There is no "balance to show" and you should not have people transfer money to your account to make it look better. That guarantees a refusal. Rather, you should ask can you afford the trip?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I do have some balance to show, and with good history of bank statement. 
The thing i am confused on - What ending balance to be shown ? Is it amount equivalent to GBP5000 or more or less can do too ?

Comment: There is no requirement for *any* particular final balance.
Your bank statements are to show two things:
That you have a steady (and legal) life and income in your home country to return to. **And** that it is within your means to afford the trip. Your "means" here is more your income than you balance.

Comment: The answer to this related question about bank statements might be helpful. [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Is there any reason not to send statements from all your accounts, if that gives a more complete view of your financial situation?

Answer (score 3):

Do not ask your father to put money in your account to beef it up so you are showing more money when you apply for a visa. We here call it funds parking. It is even worse if your father expects the money back before you travel, but even just a donation from your father just before your application looks bad.

You need to show you can afford to travel in the way you plan to travel. That means that you have enough income each month to cover the expenses you have every month with enough left over to save so you can build up money for your trip.
That is why you should show several months of bank statements as well as your savings account over the same period.

If you do not earn enough for saving up you will need to show a very strong reason for travel to UK as well as a good explanation how you get the money and why the person getting you the money is giving it to you.

When I say 'you' I mean 'you and your whole family'.

Besides you will need to show a good reason to return home, as traveling to the UK with your whole family will make the officers looking at your case wonder whether you will even want to return.
If you were to travel alone, or just with your wife or just one of the kids, you would have a stronger tie to draw you back home.

As said in the comments you do not need a particular amount of money, you need to show that you can afford to travel without getting into financial problems.
If you can not do that at this time, you may have to adjust your plans, (travel with a smaller group) or postpone your plans till you have enough money to pay for it in your savings account.

While it is not unheard of parents to give money to adult offspring for travels abroad, your father will have to proof that he has plenty of money to do so, he will likely also have to have a good reason to give you the money. If the officer thinks he is just going to give you a loan and you can not afford the travel without it, you will not get the visa.

And applying for a visa and not getting it will be risky in the longer run, the more often you are denied a visa, the harder it gets to get a visa later.

Do [read this topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1), (also mentioned in the comments on the question) as it explains in details why the visa officers do want to see the bank statements and what you should do to show them off best.